# Tensorflow, Horovod, and NVLINK NotFoundError

Tags: python, tensorflow, horovod

I'm trying to run a tensorflow neural network that runs on GPUs using **uber's horovod library**. At the same time I am trying to run a measurement script that measurements the **nvlinks** between the multiple gpus. Alas, whenever I run the file I get the following error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/pat/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/horovod
>   /tensorflow/mpi_lib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow14kernel_factory17OpKernelRegist                       rar12InitInternalEPKNS_9KernelDefEN4absl11string_viewESt10unique_ptrINS0_15OpKernelFactoryESt14default_deleteIS8_EE

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at this issue raised on the repo:

https://github.com/horovod/horovod/issues/656